# Problems with GKSession and sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error:

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

Alright, this involves a lot of network coding from [this part of a multiplayer tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12910/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-3).

Basically, I'm trying to implement a multiplayer game using GameKit as per the tutorial linked above. I put in all of the necessary network coding and more or less understand it, however I've hit a snag somewhere along the line of method calls. Basically, the setup that I have is that one device acts as the host and the rest act as the clients. I have two separate `UIViewcontroller`s for the host and clients respectively where the connection is established.

Now the thing is, the connection gets established, but it's only the host that recognizes the connection, not the client. The problem is here:

```
- (void)sendPacketToAllClients:(Packet *)packet
{
    [_players enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, Player *obj, BOOL *stop)
     {
         obj.receivedResponse = [_session.peerID isEqualToString:obj.peerID];
     }];

    GKSendDataMode dataMode = GKSendDataReliable;
    NSData *data = [packet data];
    NSError *error;
    if (![_session sendDataToAllPeers:data withDataMode:dataMode error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error sending data to clients: %@", error);
    }
}
```

This is implemented in `GameMultiplayer`, where the actual game will be implemented. What this method is supposed to be doing is sending data packets to each of the clients saying that the host received the connection request and is able to connect with them. After `[_session sendDataToAllPeers:data withDataMode:dataMode error:&error]` is called (the method in the `if` statement), this method is supposed to be triggered:

```
- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peerID inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"Game: receive data from peer: %@, data: %@, length: %d", peerID, data, [data length]);
#endif

    Packet *packet = [Packet packetWithData:data];
    if (packet == nil)
    {


        NSLog(@"Invalid packet: %@", data);
        return;
    }

    Player *player = [self playerWithPeerID:peerID];
    if (player != nil)
    {
        player.receivedResponse = YES;  // this is the new bit
    }

    if (self.isServer)
        [self serverReceivedPacket:packet fromPlayer:player];
    else
        [self clientReceivedPacket:packet];
}
```

This method is in the next part of the tutorial I linked above (which is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12930/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-4)) and is supposed to receive the packets that the host sends to all clients and implement the next methods in this networking chain. However, the method never gets called. No debug breakpoints are triggered and I get nothing in the console.

I understand if I need to provide more source material, but there is a lot of network coding already implemented, so I want to keep it down to what people need to see. Also, `[_session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil]` and `_session.delegate = self` are written in another method that is called in `GameMultiplayer`, so that's not the problem. Does anyone know what I need to fix?

EDIT: As requested, here's where GKSession is initialized:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) GKSession *session; //This is done in the header file

@synthesize session = _session; //This is done in the main file

- (void)startAcceptingConnectionsForSessionID:(NSString *)sessionID
{

    if (_serverState == ServerStateIdle)
    {
        _serverState = ServerStateAcceptingConnections;

        _connectedClients = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.maxClients];

        _session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
        _session.delegate = self;
        _session.available = YES;
    }
}
```

The session is initialized in `MatchmakingServer`, which is used in the host view controller. The session is then passed on to the main view controller of the app, which then initializes `GameMultiplayer` and sends the GKSession to it. Here's where the host view controller sends it to the main view controller:

```
- (IBAction)startAction:(id)sender
{
    if (_matchmakingServer != nil && [_matchmakingServer connectedClientCount] > 0)
    {
        NSString *name = [self.nameTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if ([name length] == 0)
                name = _matchmakingServer.session.displayName;

        [_matchmakingServer stopAcceptingConnections];

        [self.delegate hostViewController:self startGameWithSession:_matchmakingServer.session playerName:name clients:_matchmakingServer.connectedClients];
    }
}
```

and then the main view controller handles that method call here:

```
- (void)hostViewController:(MatchmakerHost *)controller startGameWithSession:(GKSession *)session playerName:(NSString *)name clients:(NSArray *)clients
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^
     {

         [self startGameWithBlock:^(GameMultiplayer *aGame)
          {
              [aGame startServerGameWithSession:session playerName:name clients:clients];
          }];
     }];
}
```

and finally, this is where that method call is implemented in `GameMultiplayer`:

```
- (void)startServerGameWithSession:(GKSession *)session playerName:(NSString *)name clients:(NSArray *)clients
{
    _clients = clients;

    const char* className = class_getName([[_clients objectAtIndex:0] class]);
    NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %s", className);

    self.isServer = YES;

    _session = session;
    _session.available = NO;
    _session.delegate = self;
    [_session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];

    _state = GameStateWaitingForSignIn;

    [self.delegate gameWaitingForClientsReady:self];

    // Create the Player object for the server.
    Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = name;
    player.peerID = _session.peerID;
    player.position = PlayerPositionBottom;
    [_players setObject:player forKey:player.peerID];

    // Add a Player object for each client.
    int index = 0;
    for (NSString *peerID in clients)
    {
        Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
        player.peerID = peerID;
        [_players setObject:player forKey:player.peerID];

        if (index == 0)
            player.position = ([clients count] == 1) ? PlayerPositionTop : PlayerPositionLeft;
        else if (index == 1)
            player.position = PlayerPositionTop;
        else
            player.position = PlayerPositionRight;

        index++;
    }

    NSLog(@"Players:");

    Packet *packet = [Packet packetWithType:PacketTypeSignInRequest];
    [self sendPacketToAllClients:packet];

//    for (int i = 0; i < [_players count]; i++) {
//        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [clients objectAtIndex:i]]);
//    }
}
```

Comment: How did you setup the GKSession object?                        GKSession * gk_session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];

Comment: [_session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];  You are passing self here, handler is the object you want the session to call when it receives data from other peers. And The handler must implement a method with the following signature:

- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context;               I am wondering, whether you are passing correct handler or not?

Comment: When it makes the `[_session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil]` method call, `self` is `GameMultiplayer`, which is what I want to be the data handler. And yes, the method you mentioned is being called in `GameMultiplayer`, as I showed in the question

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that `receiveData` is never called after the program calls `sendPacketToAllClients`, even though the tutorial claims it should be getting called

Comment: When your session acts as a server, client peers can discover your session and attempt to connect to it. When a client attempts to connect to the session, the delegate’s session:didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer: method is called to decide whether the peer should be connected. Your application calls this method to accept the request, or denyConnectionFromPeer: to reject it. Did you implement didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer? And did you set gksession's delegate?

Comment: the delegate for `GKSession` is set in the bottom chunk of code, and yes, `didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer` is implemented in `GameMultiplayer`. It doesn't seem to be getting called either, however...

Comment: Did you set  gkSession.available = YES, 
A Boolean value that determines whether or not the session wants to connect to new peers.
When available is YES, the session is visible to other peers based on its sessionMode property. When available is set to NO, it remains connected to peers, but is no longer visible to nonconnected peers. The default is NO.

Comment: Did you set the gksession's delegate? if you have set the delegate, which class is designated as its delegate?

Comment: First of all, the session's availability is set to `YES` until the game is started in `GameMultiplayer`, at which point the game has already started and the boolean is set to `NO`. The delegate is set in the bottom chunk of code of my question, in `GameMultiplayer`. I don't mean to be rude, but are you reading the question completely? You're asking about a lot of information that I've already provided

Comment: The `sendPacketToAllClients` method is called though right?

Comment: Yes, it's just that `receiveData` doesn't get called. As far as I can tell, it should be triggered as soon as `sendDataToAllPeers` is called in the `sendPacketToAllClients` declaration

Comment: i would definately implement the -(void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state method, you do have a better overview of what is happening there

Comment: Did anyone file a bug report? I am experiencing the same issue. I put a breakpoint on the line that calls `[mySession sendDataToAllPeers...]`, and the breakpoint never triggers. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling send to fast. When server realize about connection it will send confirmation to client to really establish connection - so client knows about it succeed.

If you are sending packets before that happens - it will be lost.

Just do this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sendPacketToAllClients) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

instead of:

```
[self sendPacketToAllClients];
```

I had the same problem that connection is established in different moment with small delay on client. The  best is to send first packet from client that he is ready to receive packets from server - and than proceed normally from there.

Also try debugging:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state
```

On both devices (server and client).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had my troubles with GKSession. I was interested to learn (on this site) today that GKSession is being deprecated in favor of using the **Multipeer Connectivity Framework**. With luck, Wenderlich *et al.* will do a tutorial using the new technology. :)

The system has some similarities to GKSession, so is not too hard to wrap your head around.

[Apple's doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html).